# Why SocketException inherits Win32Exception

Tags: c#, .net

[SocketException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketexception?view=net-8.0) seems to be a generic network-related exception. However, it inherits [Win32Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=net-8.0), which seems to be Windows-specific.

What's the reason for this exception to have such inheritance chain?

Comment: Win32Exception also derives from `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException` so  either, this particular exception is spedific to the Windows runtime or it's been ported/abstracted and the name no longer makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because hindsight is 20:20, and when `Socket` was originally devised in .NET Framework on Windows, it made enough sense to be selected as the implementation. When .NET Framework was ported to .NET Core, three options present themselves:

1. the oddity isn't noticed, and the inheritance chain is retained out of habit
2. the oddity is noticed, but the breaking change of swapping the inheritance chain of a not-exactly-uncommon type is seen as too risky, so the oddity is retained for compatibility reasons
3. like 2, but the decision is taken to actively break the inheritance chain, purity over compatibility

Since the inheritance chain remains, we can assume that either 1 or 2 is the case. My money would be on 2.